Expo EAS Build / Metro Bundler cannot find AppEntry.js in a fresh macbook repo setup
I just changed laptop and moved setup all the tooling on the new Macbbok M1. I'm getting this error which I cannot find any similar cases for in the web. When bundling the metro bundler is complaining that it cannot find AppEntry.js:
+ /opt/homebrew/opt/node@18/bin/node /private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/bin/cli export:embed --entry-file /var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/bitoiu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LJJ-clzmakckjofbkdarbcbhcwzorxiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LJJ/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/bitoiu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LJJ-clzmakckjofbkdarbcbhcwzorxiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LJJ/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/LJJ.app --minify false
Starting Metro Bundler
warning: Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)
/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/.:0: error: Unable to resolve module /var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js from /private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/.: 
Error: Unable to resolve module /var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js from /private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * ../../../../../../../../../var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)
  * ../../../../../../../../../var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js/index(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)
Error: Unable to resolve module /var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js from /private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * ../../../../../../../../../var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)
  * ../../../../../../../../../var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js/index(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:112:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1023:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.resolveRelativePathAsync (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:1208:12)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.metroLoadModuleContents (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:430:35)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.legacySinglePageExportBundleAsync (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:553:20)
    at exportEmbedBundleAndAssetsAsync (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:116:21)
    at exportEmbedAsync (/private/var/folders/v1/4tc4zbcn78dc64gp61qth6cr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/b88634ff-cd0d-4097-b224-3df0ad054192/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/export/embed/exportEmbedAsync.ts:68:30)

warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
note: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'LJJ' from project 'LJJ')
note: Run script build phase '[Expo] Configure project' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'LJJ' from project 'LJJ')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RN]Check rncore' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Fabric' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

I've tried deleting and rebuilding node_modules, and running npx expo-doctor reveals no issues. I really have no mode ideas about this error. I will try to build with EAS on the cloud when I have more builds beggining of the month.
Thank you in advance.

Not exactly sure why you were downvoted here but I'm pretty much experiencing the same issue with an analogous setup, a Mac Mini M2. The issue only arises while building for iOS, on local, right? Were you able to solve this one without going for builds on EAS remote servers? (my project builds there aswell)
Been struggling on this one for several days and Issues on github are similar but not identical to this one

I'm on a M2 and was going nuts on this one, it should boil down to this issue which at the moment is ongoing: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/2449
As per the suggestions from the github issue, at this precise moment in time, either change the entrypoint from
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",

to
"main": "expo/AppEntry.js",

in your package.json
Or downgrade to:
    "expo": "51.0.14",

(no tilde)
Personally tested the first solution on "expo": "~51.0.19",, can build EAS locally for both Android and iOS on any of my profiles
Edit: The issue was fixed in "expo": "~51.0.20"! https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/30340
No need anymore for the workarounds
